# Enigmial does not put the secret key into the secret keyring

Tags: pgp, gnupg, enigmail

I've been using Enigmail 1.8.2 on Thunderbird 38.5.0 from the Fedora 23 repository. I generated a key pair by using Enigmail and I can send encrypted and signed emails by using Thunderbird (or even by using other MUA).

Now I want to use the key pair from the shell or from Emacs (EasyPG). But I'm having a hard time since my secret key ring is empty:

```
$ gpg -K
$
```

How can I get my private key into my secret key ring?

Answer (score 3):

[Fedora 22 and 23 already ship GnuPG 2.1](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/gnupg2), which [merged the private keyring into the public keyring](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring). Enigmail interfaces GnuPG 2, so keys created with Enigmail and GnuPG 2.1 are stored in the public keyring file.

Use `gpg2` instead of `gpg` if you can; otherwise you'll have to export the secret keys from `gpg2` and import it to GnuPG 1  again:

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys [key-id] | gpg --import
```